# Format algorithm in two columns

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I am using the packages `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` and the `article` document class. What I am trying to do is to format a single algorithm in two columns like this:

```
----------------------------------
Algorithm 5: Title
----------------------------------

Parameters: ...

Maschine A              Maschine B
----------------------------------
...
...
                        ...
...
                        ...
                        ...
...
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Some algorithm}
  \label{alg:my_two_column_algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    % This should be on the left.
    \State $s \gets 123$
    \State Send $s$.

    % This should be on the right.
    \If{$s > t$}
      \State $r \gets 1$
    \Else
      \State $r \gets 0$
    \EndIf
    \State Send $r$.

    % This should be on the left again.
    \State \Return $r$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: output]

What I would like to achieve is this (Photoshop, no LaTeX code):

[image: desired]

The algorithm describes a network interaction, that's why I am trying to use this format. Is there a way to do this and still use algorithmic commands such as `\If` etc.? How would I format this?

I am also open to other suggestions, maybe there is an established way of presenting such algorithms?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)! When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful if you provide a _complete_, self contained example! It should include a `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really are asking. Just a starting point for the people here that want to help you.

Comment: Thank you, @AndreasStorvikStrauman! I added an example and a screenshot of the output and created an image of what I would like the output to be like (using Photoshop).